# ¿Cómo paso un valor de un componente cualquiera al componente principal App.js en reac.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Mi duda es, ¿cómo le paso al componente App.js un valor que recibo de un componente, como por ejemplo el valor del nombre del login?
Quiero pasarle este valor para a partir de ahí propagarle a todos sus hijos.

Este es el archivo index de react.js, donde definimos todas las rutas. 
Teniendo este código:

```
export default [

{
path: '/path',
children: [
  path,
],
async action({ next, render, context}) {
  const component = await next();
  if (component === undefined) return component;
  return render(
    <App context={context} mivalor={mivalor}>{component}</App>
  );
},
```

}

Alguien sabe como pasarle al componente App.js un valor que devuelva el componente "component" ?

El archivo App.js es el siguiente:

```
class App extends Component {

static propTypes = {
  context: PropTypes.shape({
      insertCss: PropTypes.func,
      setTitle: PropTypes.func,
      setMeta: PropTypes.func,
  }),
  mivalor: PropTypes.string
};

static childContextTypes = {
    mivalor: PropTypes.string
};

getChildContext() {
const context = this.props.context;
return {,
  mivalor: context.mivalor
};
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear una función en App.js que cambie el nombre del mismo, y pasarlo como *Props* al componente hijo,
en el hijo simplemente mandas a llamar la función por medio de `this.props.myFunction()`.

Otra solución sería usar una arquitectura como *Flux* o *Redux* para cambiar el estado de toda la aplicación

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name:''
    }
  }
  changeName(name){
    this.setState({name});
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h2 >My name is: {this.state.name} </h2> 
      
      <Child changeName={this.changeName}/>
      </div>
   }
 }


class Child extends React.Component{
onClick(){
  const newName = this.refs.name.value;
  this.props.changeName(newName);
}
render(){
  return(
    <div>
   <input  ref="name" />
      <button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}> Change my name </button>
    </div >
  )
}
  
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```